# Microsoft report viewer joining mulitiple tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reporting, microsoft-reporting

I'm working on the Microsoft report viewer VS2012 , I tried to generate a report from one table and I succeeded, but what if I have a query containing a Join on two or more table , in this cases how to generate the report ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a project.
You should create a dataset that has the query you want, it can be a procedura that has a join.
After that you can drag the fields from the dataset for inside of the report.

Comment: Can you please clarify more that to me (I'm new in the the world of c#) , Tuto or video from the web  ,